# onKeyUp doesn't work for KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER

Tags: android, d-pad

I have 2 activities, where I overrided the onKeyUp event:

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Key up: " + keyCode);
        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
     }
```

The first is the main activity of the application, the other one is secondary. The first works fine, but the second captures events for Left-Right-Up-Down but not for Center click. Why?

Comment: Isn't there some view that has a focus and catches the event? Take a look what the documentation of onKeyUp says: _Called when a key was released and not handled by any of the views inside of the activity. So, for example, key presses while the cursor is inside a TextView will not trigger the event (unless it is a navigation to another object) because TextView handles its own key presses._

Comment: I did not set focus manually, how can I check this?

Comment: You don't have to set it manually - for example, when there's an EditText, it will get focused automatically.

Comment: There's ImageView, Gallery and one more View.

Answer (score 5):

Since you have a Gallery in your layout, take a look at: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/Gallery.java#L1216 . It might be possible that the Gallery steals your DPAD_CENTER event (and also ENTER).

I suggest you to use [Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(android.view.KeyEvent)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#dispatchKeyEvent%28android.view.KeyEvent%29) to stop the event before it even goes to that Gallery.

Try using it like this (in your Activity):

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
  if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER) {
    // Do your stuff here.
    return true; // Consume the event (or not, your call)
  }
  return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: Log.d(TAG, "Dispatch: " + event); - this shows nothing for DPAD_CENTER, but works fine for other keys.

Comment: Ok, then I'd suggest you to paste some code of your layout and activity, so we can experiment with the actual implementation.

Comment: This helped me.  Thank you.